# getting data from server as JSON

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios, phonegap

I need to say at first that I am totally new to salesforce. I started working with this platform since last monday and I have no background. I was told to obtaine JSON data from the server on a click event. Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="getHotels" data-theme="e" data-role="button">Get hotels</div>
          <ul id="bringHotels" data-role="listview"></ul>
```

As I click the "Get hotels" button the results should be displayed in the ul below.
And here is the adress with JSON:

```
/services/apexrest/Hotels
```

I tried to obtain the data from this source with the getJSON method which usually works 
but not this time. I must mention that the app uses jquery mobile, salesforce sdk and phonegap-cordova.Thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome to SFSE, codeman. Please read the FAQ for the site. As it stands, your question is very broad ("how do I get JSON data?") and doesn't show what you have tried or any errors which makes it difficult, which will likely get the question put on hold. Have you gone through Salesforce's documentation for using callouts? They're pretty in-depth and should be enough to get you started.

Comment: @Mike Chale - thanks Mike for your advise. Could you please give some tips where can I find some documentation about this (about using callouts) ? Perhaps that would help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: JavaScript remoting: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_js_remoting_example.htm, Apex web services: http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Apex_Web_Services_and_Callouts. Try Googling for things like 'visualforce web services' or 'visualforce callouts' for other ideas/guides.